# Kafka AWS deployment, how to change disk size with no downtime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

I have a kafka cluster deployed on AWS, with 6 nodes grouped into 3 autoscaling groups, our retention period is set to 7 days. We use EBS as our kafka store. As we scale out the system, with more data, the storage is running low. We plan to double our store size.

AWS has the procedure to modify EBS volume for the EC2 instance:
- Modify the volume
- Go to the EC2 instance for this volume, run sudo resize2fs /dev/xvdf
- Wait for the volume optimization grow from 0 to 100%.
- Monitor Kafka metrics for free disk space, under replicated partitions, CPU usage, Memory usage, etc.

However, we find that we have to re-activate Kafka service after we extend file system to the new store size. Otherwise, the node doesn't accept data for any partition. Therefore, we observed under replicated partition count increasing, CPU usage tripling, memory usage rampping up.

The question is why? What's the correct way to increase the volume size without downtime?

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between downtime and a successful rolling restart.

Sounds like you'd want the latter, which is something you'd have to practice anyway if you want to ever upgrade the cluster or change server properties

1. Identify the controller (refer JMX value of 1)
2. Reboot every *other broker*, one at a time. Make sure that unclean leader election is false
3. When brokers restart, wait for replication and ISR counts to become healthy
4. Finally reboot controller, assuming it's still the same machine

Whatever you do with the host OS between these actions is up to you